# How to save all render views when rendering from command line

Tags: command-line, render-layers

I have a quite big file with which I have troubles working through the UI.
So I have seen it is possible to launch rendering from command line.
My scene is a single frame anyway with 5 render views (layers).
When I render through the UI, at the end, I can select each render result and save them manually.
But when I launch rendering from command line, even if it is shown that Blender renders all the render views (layers), at the end it saves just the first one.
This is the syntax I use from command line:

*"Path to Blender"*>blender.exe -b file.blend -o //render.png -f 1
Is it possible and, in the affirmative, how to save all the layers from command line?

Thank you!

EDIT:

this are the screenshots of a render test with 2 render layers:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

as you can see, 2 scenes are rendered (one called "cubo" - *cube* - and the other called "sfera" - *sphere*). 
But at the end Blender saves only 1 png file (and then there are some other errors that I don't know what they mean, but I suppose they don't matter because the saved file is present in the output directory)